# Como puedo mostrar un Select2 anidado en Datatable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```css
https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/461756/edit#
```

Quisiera que me ayuden en esto: Tengo un formulario con 8 *inputs*, pero ahora lo que quiero es agregar 2 *select* anidados (combobox anidado); el *select* anidado lo hice con 2 tablas en *mysql* las cuales son: `categoría` y `área`. Por ejemplo, al seleccionar `Sistemas` en el otro select me da: `windows7,windows8,windows10,` etc. la cual esta perfecto.

Mi duda es: ¿cómo puedo hacer que los 8 inputs y el select se "muestren o concatenen"? como por ejemplo:

```
fecha=13-06-21,nombre="luis"... select1 sistemas,select2 win10,button=registrar
```

Para luego mostrar todos los datos registrados en un datatable.

Cualquier pedido de imagen por favor me lo hacen saber, de antemano gracias.

```js
Mi vista en js

function init(){
$("#detalle_form").on("submit",function(e){
guardaryeditar(e);  
});
/* select*/
$('#val-select2').select2();
$('#cmbarea').select2();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$.post("../../controller/partes.php?op=insert",{usu_id:usu_id},function(data){

data = JSON.parse(data);

$('#part_id').val(data.part_id);
llenartabla(data.part_id);
/* select */
});
$.post("../../controller/categoria.php?op=combo",function(data,status){  
   $('#val-select2').html(data);

});
$("#val-select2").change(function(){
    $("#val-select2 option:selected").each(function () {
        cat_id = $(this).val();

$.post("../../controller/area.php?op=combo",{cat_id:cat_id},function(data,status){  
    $('#cmbarea').html(data);

    });
});
});
});
```

```html
Mi input + select + button

 <!--   telefono -->
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-lg-12 col-form-label" for="telefono">Telefono <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" placeholder="927552185">
</div>
</div>
 
 <!--   Select1 -->
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-12" for="telefono">select1 </label>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<select class="js-select2 form-control" id="val-select2" name="val-select2" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Elija una area ..">
<option></option>
</select>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Select2 -->
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-12" for="telefono">Sub Areas</label>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<select class="js-select2 form-control" id="cmbarea" name="cmbarea" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Elija una area ..">
<option></option><!-- Required for data-placeholder attribute to work with Select2 plugin -->

</select>
</div>
</div>

  <!--  button -->
<div class="form-group row"> 
<div class="col-6 text-right">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-alt-primary" id="btnguardar">
<i class="fa fa-save ml-5"></i> Guardar 
</button>
</div>
</div>
mi controlador
   

  case "listar":
        $datos=$partes->list_partes($_POST["usu_id"]);
        $data= Array();
        foreach($datos as $row){
            $sub_array = array();
          
            $sub_array[] = "MDJN-".$row["part_id"];
            $sub_array[] = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row["fecha_crea"]));
            
            $sub_array[] = $row["telefono"];
          
            $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" onClick="ver('.$row["part_id"].');"  id="'.$row["part_id"].'" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-icon"><div><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i></div></button>';
            $data[] = $sub_array;
        }
```

Comment: ¿Quieres que se concatenen o quieres mostrarlos en un datatable?

Comment: Mostrarlo en un datatable junto con los demás datos

Comment: Los datos que se ingresan en el formulario, previamente los guardas en la base de datos? `guardaryeditar(e); `

Comment: si, los guardo en mi bd

Comment: Ok, me parece que tienes una solución sencilla con solo una función, pero no veo el código de datatables. ¿Lo que necesitas entonces es guardar esos datos en la base y a su vez actualizar tu vista? Para mi sería obvio que la tabla donde guardas es la misma de donde se alimenta el datatables, correcto ?

Comment: Lo que necesito es prácticamente mostrar los datos del select y se muestre con mis otros datos en el datatable, me disculparas en como agrego mi código del controlador, pero soy nuevo en esto. Tengo lo que son 4 tablas las cual el primero es (partes), la cual almaceno todos mis inputs, de ahi tengo lo q es otra tabla con el nombre (categoría)que esta anidada con lo que es (área). 
Los datos de los 2 select las obtengo desde mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

después de los comentarios queda un poco más claro.
Primero lo que preguntas originalmente, para concatenar los valores del formulario podrías utilizar:

`let concatenados = $( "#id-form" ).serialize();` Esto concatenará los valores y los delimitará por `&`.

Pero si ya guardas los datos en la base y tienes el código que genera el datatable con ajax, simplemente utiliza `ajax.reload()` lo que hace es actualizar tu tabla y mostrará los últimos datos, en este caso los que guardaste previamente. A continuación un ejemplo que actualiza la tabla cada 30 seg

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: "data.json"
} );
 
setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
}, 30000 );
```

Importante mencionar que la variable `table` es global, para que así puedas hacer uso del método `reload()` cada que guardes o edites los datos.